# The space efficiency of the iterative Factorial(n)

Tags: algorithm

Since we have register named result , I believe we do not have to have stack to save the result in memory we just need 1 space in memory.
So is my assume correct s(n) in big O(1).

Comment: If `n!` still fits into your machine's register, yes. However that is only true for rather small `n`.

Answer (score 0):

The space complexity is given by the number of bits of the result. Using Stirling's approximation, `log n!` is `O(n log n)`.